# How bitrate changes with screen size

Tags: video, encoding, bitrate

I'm trying to DVDrip a 320x240 screen .m4v video. Is there some way to mathematically know the bitrate for the required screen size so that there will be no distortions and you can know the closest accurate bitrate as possible without taking or giving too much?

Comment: Have a look at http://forum.doom9.org/ or http://www.videohelp.com because this is probably not the best place to ask the question. And frankly, as long as you compress the video using some lossy encoder, you will see "distortions". You can use quality based encoding if you can't make a good estimate of the bit-rate required.

Answer (score 0):

The common way nowadays is to use [Constant Rate Factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_Rate_Factor)

1 is best quality, 23 is default.

```
ffmpeg -i in.VOB -crf 10 -s qvga out.m4v
```

**FFmpeg will assume**

H.264 video codec

High profile

AAC audio codec

128 kbit/s audio bitrate